# analogue to Windows combination ctrl+alt+del

Tags: monitor

Combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Windows calls Task manager. You can see running processes and kill any task. Is there anything like this in Ubuntu? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go:
 System—>Preferences –> keyboard Shortcuts

And add a keystroke shortcut to the gnome-system-monitor.